# Define multiple return values

Tags: typescript

How do I describe the type if a function returns 2 values?

I have this function:

```
const firstFunction = (input: number) => {
  const firstValue = input;
  const innerFunction = (funcInput: number) => {
    funcInput * input;
  };
  return [firstValue, innerFunction];
};
```

And I call it like this:

```
const [value, innerFunction] = firstFunction(1);
```

When I call `innerFunction` TypeScript isn't sure if it is a function. Right now it thinks it is:

```
number | ((funcInput: number) => void)
```

How can I tell TypeScript the second return value is a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a [*tuple*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type to do that effectively:

```
const firstFunction = (input: number): [number, (funcInput: number) => void] => { ... };
                                    // ^-----------------------------------^
```

Comment: @TijlIvens no problem, but please note the guidance at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a type/interface that you would return for more readability:

```
interface MyInterface {
    myValue: number;
    myFunction: number => void
}

const firstFunction = (input: number): MyInteface => { ... }; // Return will be a bit different as well
```

You can also return the type directly:

```
const firstFunction = (input: number) => {
// ...
return {
      value,
      innerFunction
   }
};
```

The solution with tuple will not give you name as it's position based if I remember correctly.

It's up to you to chose the best approach, I do prefer names for fields to avoid misinterpretation.