# How do you return multiple values from a typescript function

Tags: typescript

I'd like a Typescript function to return multiple values. How do I do this? Also - how do I declare the types?

For example I want to achieve something like this:

```
let [text, value] = ReturnTwoValues("someinputstring")
```

Comment: You can't. You have to return an object. (Arrays are objects, often used for exactly this use case.)

Comment: Did you research this? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679094/define-multiple-return-values. Note that only the typing part is really a [tag:typescript] question, otherwise it's just JavaScript.

Comment: TS is just JS with types; in JS, functions return a single value.  If you want that single value to be an object or array with multiple properties, that's great, but you *don't* seem to want that, so I think the answer to this question is probably just "you can't".  The difference between "multiple return values" and "a single tuple-typed return value" is somewhat semantic, though, so... maybe that's what you want?

Comment: Valid point.  I'm improved the question

Answer (score 71):

Function definition:

```
public ReturnTwoValues(someInput: string): [string, boolean] {
    const text = "hello"
    const value = true
    return [text, value]
}
```

Caller:

```
let [text, value] = ReturnTwoValues("someinputstring")
```

Comment: *"Without creating an object." Arrays are objects. I'd at least open with "you can't." :-)

Comment: @Lars But you're still returning an array, which is an object. I thought the original question was how to do it without returning an object.

Comment: Oh, you answered your own question, but `[text, value]` is an object that you created, so it doesn't answer the question as asked without some clarifying info about what constitutes "multiple return values" and what constitutes an object in JS

Comment: It gives errors in TypeScript 3.7.3: Type `[string, boolean]` is not assignable to `(string|boolean)[]

Answer (score 28):

```
public ReturnTwoValues(someInput: string): {text:string, value:boolean} {
    const text = "hello"
    const value = true
    return {text, value}
}

let {text, value} = ReturnTwoValues("some irrelevant string");

console.log(text) //output hello
console.log(value) // output value
```

Answer (score 7):

**Note:** This answer was written when the question asked how to return multiple values *without creating an object*. The question was later edited to remove that requirement.

---

Of course, since a function returns one value, then the only way to return more than one value is to wrap them together in some object; as others have noted in the comments, an array is a kind of object. However, you don't have to create a *new* object for this, so *technically* what you're asking for is possible. Here's a solution which uses the function itself as the return value, so it meets the criterion of not creating an object when the function is called.

```
interface Foo {
    x: string,
    y: number,
    (): Foo
}

const foo = (() => {
    foo.x = 'bar';
    foo.y = 1;
    return foo;
}) as Foo;

let { x, y } = foo();
console.log(x); // bar
console.log(y); // 1
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIAeAXMgM5hSgDmANPoQJ5kgCuAtgEbQOHIAKAJRkM6XAF9cuBOhCVkMTMgC8g4aoB8ORgSXoAdEVXIA5FzhRTAbl2LMBpiYCMt-lAhg2UEPfS2JIWQ4cjRMW1wAG08cYjpkJwkTfWFbWXl0aINI9BoBIiFrZAB6YuQLKBk5ckyIbNyBJkKSsudcIA)

I don't recommend actually doing this, though; since it doesn't return a fresh object each time, it can lead to bugs if you retain a reference to the return value and expect its properties to stay the same.

Comment: you don't really need to declare an interface if you don't want to. Declaring an interface there may be a little bit of overengineering , specially if your code is relatively clear

Comment: For example, let {min,max} = someObject.getMinMaxValues();

Comment: @JuanVilar The interface is the easiest way to tell the compiler to allow assignments to `foo.x` and `foo.y`; otherwise it will give a type error, saying the function `foo` does not have those properties.